# What Exception should be thrown from Propery Set?

Tags: .net, language-agnostic, exception

In .NET, what type of exception should be thrown if someone passes an illegal value to the `set { }` part of a property?

Example:

```
public string Provider
{
    get { return _provider; }
    set
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) throw new Exception("Provider cannot be null or empty."); //what type of exception should be thrown here instead?
        _provider = value;
    }
}
```

---

**Note:**

I'm asking this question as it applies to .NET, but it could apply to many other languages as well. So if you have a good answer that applies to something other than the .NET framework, please post!

Answer (score 7):

[ArgumentException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception.aspx), ArgumentOutOfRangeException, ArgumentNullException or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, I'd disagree with Jon B regarding when to throw the exception - if it is thrown on the call to set() it will capture the context of when the invalid value was set.  On the other hand, if you just set it to some dummy value and throw the exception elsewhere, then depending on the approach you take, the client will either see the dummy value with no indication that this was not the value actually set, or they will receive an exception that doesn't give them any idea of who is responsible for the invalid state or how to rectify it.

Now in some situations this technique might make sense - if for some unavoidable reason the property is extremely volatile, and you've decided that it's fine for illegal properties to be set transiently, but (based on some external synchronisation) the client is not allowed to retrieve the property until it is known to be a legal, stable value.  This isn't great either, but I'm sure it's possible to be in a situation where you can't help this situation.

And since you asked about languages other than .NET, in Java I would use an IllegalArgumentException in the general case - perhaps a good old NullPointerException if the argument is null.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Andrzej. The exception should be thrown in the "set" because a property should NEVER be set to an invalid value and you need to "capture the context of when the invalid value was set"

I use one of ArgumentException classes because "under the hood" a "set" is a call to an automatically created method named 'CLASSNAME'.set_'PROPERTYNAME'(value)

For example

```
class MyClass
{
  string name;

  public string Name {
    get {
      return name;
    }
    set {
      if (value==null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("value", "The value of the property Name cannot be set to null.");
      }
      name = value;
    }
  }

}
```

Internally this creates two methods

```
public string get_Name()
```

and

```
public void set_Name(string value)
```

If you display the stack trace this is where the exception will be thrown from.

That's why I always include text like "The value of the property Name..." in the message so that the user of the property can see where the exception was thrown because there will not be a method called set_SOMEPROPERTY(SOMETYPE value) visible to the user of the class library.

(besides, this is what you are suppose to do according to the "NET Framework 4 -Design Guidelines for Exceptions, Catching and Throwing Standard Exception Types ([Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229007.aspx))
About halfway down the page under "ArgumentException, ArgumentNullException, and ArgumentOutOfRangeException" it states "Do use value for the name of the implicit value parameter of property setters")

Answer (score 0):

I would not throw an exception in that case. If the property is a string, then I can set it to "" or null. The exception should be thrown when I try to use that property (like in a Connect() function), with the message indicating the function failed because the property was invalid.

Comment: For this specific example this may make sense.  If, however, the value was used in the setter for more than storing, I'd still throw.

Comment: @ctacke - the setter should only be used for storage of the value. If more action is needed, then a SetProvider(string value) function should be used.

Comment: What exception should be thrown then from the Connect() function?

Comment: @Terrapin - I would probably create my own exception for this. You might prefer the SetProvider(string value) solution instead, and throw ArgumentException from there.

Comment: @Jon B: What if the setter also raises an event and the event contains the data?  Should it raise with null or inform the setter through an Exception?  I'd assert that it's best to not send out invalid data at all than to rely on any number of unknown receivers to look for it.

Comment: Agreed - SetProvider is probably more logical in this specific case.

Comment: @ctackle - I would have the event report the invalid data, if the event is simply "OnPropertyChanged".